# What do I need to do to get my list to show up in Data Grid View?

Tags: linq, datagridview

What do I need to do to get my list to show up in Data Grid View?

I have a Data Grid View in a .net Forms app.

If I do a linq query and assign the result to the Grid view's DataSource I see that data fine.

However I want slightly different columns and data. So I made a class to represent the data types I want and put them in a list. And then I assign this list to the Datasource.

This compiles find and runs but then no data shows up on the view. But if I debug it there is clearly data in this list.

why doesn't the list show up? some interface I need to implement?

Example:

```
        var myDataItem = (from listing in _db.Items
                        select listing);

        List<ItemViewModel> _listOftems= new List<ItemViewModel>();
        foreach (Item_aItem in myDataItem )
        {
            _listOftems.Add(new ItemViewModel(item.property));
        }

        // linq version works, list does not, IE what is commented out does not work
        dgvITems.DataSource = myDataItem ; // _listOfItems;
```

Comment: Can you show some of the work you've done that is not working?  Will help us determine what is going wrong :)  You could even show what works.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't gotten confused about what works and what doesn't? In my testing the linq example when bound as is does not work (because the query does not get materialized) but the list example works perfectly. If your example is correct, is there something you have left out? The list should work just as you show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely:  ItemViewModel is exposing public fields, not public properites.  The DataGridView can only bind to public properties.